# Add image via google docs script while script is closed

Tags: javascript, image, documentation

I am currently trying to add an image into a google doc and it is working fine. The only thing is,
it is only appending the image, when the script editor is open..
Am I missing something?

Here's the relevant code:

```
insertImage(resultImage);

function insertImage(res){
var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(res);
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendImage(resp.getBlob());
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, by creating a menu item, which calls another function.